# Can't link / connect UIScrollView?

Tags: ios5, header, uiscrollview, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I have created a UIScrollView in the Interface Builder.
But i can't link / connect it in my header!

I'm using:

Xcode 4.2.1

iOS 5 SDK

Comment: Did you Ctrl-drag to the header to create an outlet or action?

Comment: Yes, i did but it still won't work!

Comment: Solved, i added my custom class to my UIScrollView and ViewController and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, i added my custom class to my `UIScrollView` and `ViewController` and it worked!